# Strong number problem in C++ but something is wrong with my code

Tags: c++

I'm coding for the Strong number problem and when I run it, i passed 3 cases. But when I run 4th case nothing happens.

I passed: 1, 2, 145 but 40585.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Get(int n);
int Factorial(int n, int sum);

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    int n;

    cout << "Enter. \n";
    cin >> n;
    if (n == Get(n))
    {
        cout << "True. \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "False. \n";
    }

    return 0;
}

int Get(int n)
{
    static int sum = 0;
    if (n / 10) 
    {
        Get (n / 10);
    }
    return sum += Factorial(n % 10, 1);
}

int Factorial(int n, int sum)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        return Factorial(n - 1, sum *= n);
    }
}
```

I don't know why, so pls help me !

Comment: Note that the `int` range overflows very quickly with factorial.

Comment: You call `Factorial` with `n%10` which can be `0`. But `Factorial` doesn't handle `0` well. You can change the `if` in `Factorial` to `if (n <= 1)`.

Comment: @wohlstad tks i know where i'm wrong now. I forget to add n equal to 0 in Factorial function.

Comment: what is the Strong number problem?

Comment: Firstly, factorial(0) is 1 (by definition, for various reasons). Secondly ... you only need 10 different factorials; you might as well just work them out once and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in this line:

```
return sum += Factorial(n % 10, 1);
```

You call `Factorial` with `n % 10` which can be `0`.

This is not handled well by `Factorial` (it will recurse infinitely with negative values for `n`).

You can fix it by changing the recursion stop condition in `Factorial` to:

```
if (n <= 1)
{ 
   // ... 
}
```

**A side note:**

If you can implement a function using iteration (i.e. loops) instead of recursion - this is usually recommended. This is because recursion uses the stack which is usually relatively small.

For calculating factorial you have to cope with an additional issue of `int` overflowing very fast - 13! is already too big to be stored in a 32 bit integer. You can handle it by e.g. using a 64 bit integer or some big number library for bigger values.

However - in this specific case since the `Factorial` is calculated for a max value of 9 both issues are OK (although I would still prefer using one simple loop for factorial).

As @lastchance [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411751/strong-number-problem-in-c-but-something-is-wrong-with-my-code/75411864#comment133061595_75411751), you can also keep all the required 10 values (for 0! .. 9!) in a precalculated array.